# How to get profile of user I have binded as using ldapjs

Tags: node.js, ldap, openldap, ldapjs

I'm using [ldapjs](https://npmjs.com/package/ldapjs) package. I'm using this code, which allows me
bind using `readonly` credentials to ldap server and extract one of users profile from `ou=people`.

```
'use strict';

// Figure 1

const ldap = require('ldapjs');

const ldapClient = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:389'
});

const username = 'cn=readonly,dc=vodolaz095,dc=life';
const password = 'readonly';

ldapClient.bind(
  username,
  password,
  function (error) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    console.log('bind performed');

    ldapClient.search('ou=people,dc=vodolaz095,dc=life', {
      filter: `(uid=vodolaz095)`,
      scope: 'one',
      attributes: ['uid', 'dn', 'cn', 'mail']
    }, function (error, res) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      res.on('searchEntry', function (data) {
        // console.log('Data found', data);
        console.log('Data object', JSON.stringify(data.object, null, 2));
      });
      res.once('error', function(error){
        throw error;
      });
      res.once('end', function () {
        console.log('Completed');
        process.exit(0)
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Now, i change username and password to limited user's ones, i have extracted via `readonly` credentials and execute same code:

```
// same code as in figure 1

const username = 'uid=vodolaz095,ou=people,dc=vodolaz095,dc=life';
const password = 'thisIsNotAPassword123';

// same code as in figure 1
```

I can bind to ldap server, its ok. But  when i try to get myself profile, it returns me NoSuchObjectError: No Such Object error

So, question is: how in `openldap`  can i get profile of user i have binded as ?
Like, how can i make `whoami` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the entry of the user you binded as by setting the `base` search with your bindDN, and set the scope to `base` (without any filter).

So if `username` is the bindDN, this should work :

```
ldapClient.search(username, {
  scope: 'base',
  attributes: ['uid', 'dn', 'cn', 'mail']
}
```